# How to keep the duplicate letters in enter() when update() already have that letter in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been learning D3 these days. Quite a lot fun.
There is a question:

When there is a letter, like "o" in the update(), then the enter() has two same letters "o o" and the current update() would have only one "o".
But how do I make the duplicated letters in the enter() still exists when get into update()?

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/2pB5J/5/
In this code, I would expect "54321" -> "there is an o" --> "there are two oo"

```
var alphabet = "5 4 3 2 1".split(" ");

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

function update(data) {

  // DATA JOIN
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

  // UPDATE
  // Update old elements as needed.
  text.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30 ; });

  // ENTER
  // Create new elements as needed.
  text.enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y", 70)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // EXIT
  // Remove old elements as needed.
  text.exit()
      .attr("class", "exit")
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("y", -60)
      .attr("x", 10)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();
}

// The initial display.
update(alphabet);

var i = 0;
    words = [

        "There is an o".split(""),
        "There are two oo".split(""),

    ];

    setInterval(function() {
        update(words[i]);
        i++
        //if(i == 3) {
        //    i = 0;
        //}
    }, 1500);


// Shuffles the input array.
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m], array[m] = array[i], array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `.data()` computes joins based on the data and duplicates appear only once -- by design. In your fiddle, I'm getting each letter only once (including "e").

Comment: Hi Lars, if there are duplicate letters, like the 'e' in my case, I want to show them as they are, which means "there" should not be "ther" but "there" instead. As you mentioned .data() make the duplicate data appear only once. But sometime, I need to show the duplicate letters as well, in my case the dup letters. Thanks

Comment: Well you can use a different key function (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/2pB5J/6/), but then you won't get all of the "new" letters. You basically have to find a way to tell D3 what's new and what's there already.

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d; });
```

You tell d3 to treat the letter as the data's id. And having multiple o's will then lead to the same id "o" being multiple times in your data whoch will of course break the whole thing.

How about taking the letter and it's position as id? Which would be:

```
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data, function(d, i) { return d+i.toString(); });
```

Side note:
Your setInterval function will try to access array indexes that are not existent which will lead to errors. Try something like:

```
var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
    alert(words[i]);
    update(words[i]);
    i++
    if(i === 2) {
        clearInterval(updateInterval);
    }
}, 1500);
```

This is what it looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/2pB5J/8/